# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation using Canvas Draw in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-canvas

I am using canvasDraw and it work fine in my desktop, but when i run in android this error appears: **Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation**.

Now i explore the possible solutions, as set property of css touchAction:none in the canvas component or addEventlistener touchstart to document and nothing works. Please help me, the name of the library is **react-canvas-draw**

Comment: Do you add events? If not, then you need to file a bug with the library you are using.

Comment: No, why should it happen?